# Disable recpacha for contact form 7 specific form

Tags: plugins

I am trying to automate contact form 7 submissions via curl. But I am stuck bcoz of recapcha it gives me spam status whenever I send a post request.

[image]

How do I disable recapcha on a specific form?

Answer (score 0):

For particular form I don't know it's possible or not but yes you can disable that on particular page using below filter, I have used and it's working fine for me:

```
function contactform_dequeue_scripts() {
    if (is_singular()) {
        $post = get_post();
        if (has_shortcode($post->post_content, 'contact-form-7')) {
            wp_dequeue_script('contact-form-7');
            wp_dequeue_script('google-recaptcha');
            wp_dequeue_style('contact-form-7');
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'contactform_dequeue_scripts', 99);
```

Check once maybe it helps to you for resolving your issue.

Comment: it will disable style and javascript not the server-side validation